# How to read bytes-literal from txt?

Tags: python

I have a word vector file with the words as a bytes literal followed by vector values, like this:

> b'word' 0.04683 0.43684 0.24568 ...

How do I read the word from it as bytes in order to properly decode it and rewrite the line as a normal string?

> word 0.04683 0.43684 0.24568 ...

edit: reworded to bytes literal

edit 2: I found the solution: use ast.literal_eval().

Comment: Did someone write, in text mode, a bytes object to create `b'word' 0.04683 0.43684 0.24568`...? Don't do that. Write a `str` object in text mode, or a bytes object in binary mode. There is no such thing as "bytes format", that represents a *python bytes literal*, which is meant for writing *source code*, not as a data storage format.

Comment: yes, that is what I have